# Rails runner throwing "undefined local variable or method" error for simple script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods

When we invoke this command, `rails runner test.rb -e production`, we see this error:

```
test.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `hello' for main:Object (NameError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:51:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/runner.rb:51:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:64:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Contents of test.rb:

```
hello

def hello
        puts "hi"

end
```

Why is this happening? We're on Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
hello # remove this one.

def hello
        puts "hi"

end
```

See the introspection :

```
defined? hello #=> nil # so here Ruby doesn't know who is "hello",and your call to hello thus throws the error.
def hello
        puts "hi"
end
defined? hello #=> "method"
hello #=> "hi"
```

Answer (score 6):

Because you call a method before you declare it.

```
def hello
  puts "hi"
end

hello
```